# Moving files in bulk to folders according to a key word in the file and folder name

Tags: file-move

I have several files named like this: Name 39W04150167 7015 0640 0000 2087 5834

I have several folders named like this: 39W04150167

I would like to transfer all files to their respective folders. The folder names and matching key word in the file names are unique and do not repeat.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I have Quick Move Manager that enables file moving based on a Regex Builder. But I'm also fine with a batch file or using powershell. I'm almost a total novice with coding so detailed instructions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your OS is in the unix family,

`$ mv 39W04150167[0-9]* 39W04150167`